# Why is grease pencil low quality aliased/ have jagged edges in Blender 2.80?

Tags: grease-pencil, antialiasing

My grease pencil strokes are all jagged/low quality in both the viewport and basic rendering.

I tried increasing smoothness on all stroke sliders in the GP Options panel and changing render engines with no luck.

[image: The edges of the plane are smooth but the grease pencil has aliasing along most edges.]

In some cases, closer up they appear less low quality.

I’m using Blender 2.8 …2c261b branch: Blender 2.7, on an NVIDIA GeForce 750m on OSX 10.14.3.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have masking enabled? Antialiasing stops working with masked layers in my case (blender-2.80.0-git.07f6be87a97e-windows64)

Comment: Thanks for replying! No, I haven't used masks. Is it enabled by default?